# keep subfigures inside the page

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I insert subfigures using the `\subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

As can be seen, image c is already outside the page. I would like to keep the figure inside the page.

How to achieve this without inserting `\\` manually?

Comment: Do you want c to continue in the next line or reduce the size?

Comment: I already fixed the size - `width=0.5\textwidth`. Therefore, I am looking for a line break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide possible breaking points for a line break, you could add `\hfill` between the subfloats. As the first two images occupy anyway the whole line, ot does not hurt there and the third image can go to a new line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfloat[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
  }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please remind the purpose of `%`?

Comment: @Viesturs Otherwise an additional space would be inserted at every line end. You'll notice the white gap between the two pictures in your original code and there is an overfull box warning even if there are just two of the images.

Answer (score 2):

if you fixed image width to `0.5\textwidth`, than apparently the third image should be placed on the next line. for this insert empty line after the second image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as you can see, your selection of the image width cause, that image to touch each other. i would selece slightly smaller width, for example `0.48\textwidth` and between first and second image insert `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]